# RecycleView выравнивание при фокусировании

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть `RecycleView`, который показывает горизонтальный список элементов. На элементе есть кнопка, которая должна выделяться с пульта. При наведении фокуса на кнопку, сам элемент показываться ровно на то расстояние, чтобы показыть кнопку, но остальная часть элемента остаеться невидемой.
Как сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как надо(картинка полностью выдвинулась):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 this.mRVThemes.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    this.mThemesAdapter=new ThemesAdapter((HomeActivity)getActivity(),this.mManager);
    this.mRVThemes.setAdapter(this.mThemesAdapter);
```

Код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.app.ugooslauncher.elements.UgoosRelativeLayout    
android:id="@+id/rlBackItem"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivBackItem"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/settings_backs_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/settings_backs_height" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ivBackItem"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ivBackItem">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/themes_download" />
</RelativeLayout>




</com.app.ugooslauncher.elements.UgoosRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: приведите код RecycleView пожалуйста, желательно вместе с разметкой